# Hello developers how you doin'? I need your help right now! this is issue by for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Here in my Django project I encountered loop error. I am good at loops such as while and or, but I don't know why this is happening?

views.py

Main goal doing this I want to attach address of participant to whole bunches of data.

(types of models and models_of_address are in dict)

```py
def participants(request):
    lst = []
    models = Model1.objects.all().values()
    models_of_address = Model2.objects.all().values()
    if (models and models_of_address) is not None:
        for model, model_address in models, models_of_address:
            model["address"] = model_address
            print(" ")
            lst.append(model)
        print(lst)
    else:
        lst.append("something")
    return render(request, "BasicSite/view.html", {"lst": lst})
```

Here in return keyword I was returning value: "lst"
then lst value realy confused.

Comment: You are iterating over `models, models_of_address` which will loop two times becuase they are two things. It won't loop over every `models` and `models_of_address` as you are expecting it to.

Comment: Also, type of `models` and `models_of_address` will be list (a QuerySet list to be exact). Also, if Model1 directly related to Model2, why not set a `ForeignKey` in `Model1`

Comment: I want to know what an *or* loop is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop over multiple list at time you might consider using `itertools`

```py
import itertools 
for (model, model_address) in itertools.zip_longest(models, models_of_address):
    model["address"] = model_address
    # Do your work
```

If I understood your problem this might give the solution, try to focus on giving more details in the question